# Use json data that updates after given time

Tags: javascript, json

Okay so I am making this race schedule and I have it in json like so:

```
{
    "races": [
        {
            "title": "Boston race",
            "location": "Boston MA",
            "dates": "12-14 Jan"
        },
        {
            "title": "New York race",
            "location": "New York NY",
            "dates": "1-2 Feb"
        },
        {
            "title": "Austin race",
            "location": "Austin TX",
            "dates": "29-30 Feb"
        },
        {
            "title": "LA race",
            "location": "LA CA",
            "dates": "12-14 March"
        },
        {
            "title": "Atlanta race",
            "location": "Atlanta GE",
            "dates": "1-2 April"
        },
        {
            "title": "Kansas City race",
            "location": "Kansas City KS",
            "dates": "29-30 May"
        },
        {
            "title": "Richmond race",
            "location": "Richmond VA",
            "dates": "12-14 Jun"
        },
        {
            "title": "La race",
            "location": "LA CA",
            "dates": "1-2 July"
        },
        {
            "title": "Austin race",
            "location": "Austin TX",
            "dates": "29-30 Aug"
        }
    ]
}
```

The dates and titles are just dummy ones for simplicity but basically I want to have a little box which says when the next race is, where and the dates. The tricky part is that I want it to change displaying say "next race" Austin to "next race" LA's at 4:00pm race time. Now to make it harder the timezones are different and I want it to be timezone specific. Everyone's changes at the same time but at 4:00pm after the race. So the Texas race would change at 4:00pm after the race and the people in LA would see it at 2:00pm because of timezones.

A.can you set it to change at a given time

B.Can it be specific to 4:00pm after the races timezone or will I need to convert all of them to the same timezone's time.

Is this possible with just javascript and thank you for your time.

I want the date changes to be year specific as well, something like 3/23/2011 change @4pm

How would I set this up. JS and html if its tricky please.

Comment: where will this json be consumed/displayed? in a browser? if so, you would have to know the timezone of where the browser is located to show the correct time to the user. or you register your users and they tell you, in which timezone they live. you should not keep different time zones in your data.

Comment: Basically I just want like a small box which says next race: then the data is under it in bullets, I can style it later as to the time zones could I simply set them all to the same timezone and have it display based on that timezone for people who are not located there.  I guess my fear is that it will change at different times for everyone when I want it to change simultaneously.

Comment: You need to store integer timestamps then. Timezone effect would be applied automatically for each client upon `new Date(timestamp)`.

Comment: where would I put that? Inside json?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Add a key to your JSON for the display date. It would store the date as a `JSON.stringify()` version of the date, which stores the time zone.
2. When determining which one to show, convert that `JSON.stringify` string into a date (`(new Date(JSON.parse(dateVal))`)
3. Then convert that date to UTC time and make the comparison in UTC time from that the browser is reporting (`dateVal.UTC() > new Date().UTC()`)

You shouldn't have to ask for timezone as long as you are willing to use the one that the browser thinks it is in.

### UPDATE:

Here is a jsfiddle example: http://jsfiddle.net/pseudosavant/wxwP7/
Keep in mind that the JSON.stringify object/method only has native support back to IE8, so if you (very unfortunately) must support lower than IE8 then you'll need to use a polyfill for it such as Douglas Crockford's [JSON.js](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js).

Comment: I hate to have to ask this but can you give me an example of this because I cant find it anywhere.

Comment: Sure, but can you clarify exactly when you would expect for the "next race" to change?

Comment: Each would change at a different time because of their locations.  I want to set a date for each to change.  Example: Boston to new York would be at jan 14 9:00pm utc. Austin to La would be Feb 29 10:00 utc

Comment: Could you just set up a if else based on the date in JavaScript and then reference the json array for data?

Comment: No problem. If that answers it, would you mind up-voting my answer and accepting it?

Comment: Ill make you a deal since you need 15 rep and I have 13 I will as soon as I can.

Comment: No it glitched or something, I finally was able to accept it and then it unaccepted it.  Fixed

Comment: Cool. It just seemed so weird to have a month old solution get unaccepted.